# Commerce Kickstart: How do I fix a SQL error on string length after using Features Override to save customizations?

Tags: commerce, features

After reading the update instructions on Commerce Kickstart ([Installing & Upgrading](https://drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2/install)), I attempted to use the Features Override module to save my customizations/configuration prior to updating to the most current version of Commerce Kickstart. I have changed menus, user profiles, etc. and would like to keep those updates intact.

I followed the instructions posted on the project and generated a "Feature.tar" file.

Attempt #1:

1. Selected all items shown in Features Override dropdown (179 items)
2. Downloaded the file
3. Enabled the new feature through "Modules" UI
4. Received this set of error msgs [truncated for demo purposes]:

   PDOException: SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'info' at row 1: INSERT INTO {system} (filename, name, type, owner, info) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => sites/all/modules/features_override_0916/features_override_0916.module [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => features_override_0916 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => module [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => a:12:{s:4:"name";s:25:"Features Override 09-2016";s:4:"core";s:3:"7.x";s:7:"package";s:8:"Features";s:12:"dependencies";a:2:{i:0;s:18:"commerce_kickstart";i:1;s:4:"node";}s:8:"features";a:2:{s:12:"features_api";a:1:{i:0;s:5:"api:2";}s:23:"features_override_items";a:153:{i:0;s:61:"facetapi.search_api@product_display:block:field_blog_category";i:1;s:58:"facetapi.search_api@product_display:block:field_brake_type";i:2;s:56:"facetapi.search_api@product_display:block:field_hub_type";i:3;s:64:"facetapi.search_api@product_display:block:field_intended_use_alt";i:4;s:59:"facetapi.search_api@product_display:block:field_primary_use";i:5;s:85:"facetapi.search_api@product_display:block:field_product:commerce_price:amount_decimal";i:6;s:71:"facetapi.search_api@product_display:block:field_product:field_axle_size";i:7;s:71:"facetapi.search_api@product_display:block:field_product:field_build_kit";i:8;s:67:"facetapi.search_api@product_display:block:field_product:field_color";i:9;s:72:"facetapi.search_api@product_display:block:field_product:field_frame_size";i:10;s:86:"facetapi.search_api@product_display:block:field_product:field_product_specific_options";i:11;s:73:"facetapi.search_api@product_display:block:field_product:field_wheel_sizes";i:12;s:64:"facetapi.search_api@product_display:block:field_topic_related_to";i:13;s:25:"field_base.commerce_price";i:14;s:30:"field_base.field_blog_category";i:15;s:23:"field_base.field_images";i:16;s:54:"field_instance.commerce_product-product-

Attempt #2

1. Same as above
2. Generated the file & saved it directly to the server under "Advanced Options"
3. On refresh, received same error msg as above.

I watched an Acquia tutorial on Features that seemed to show the creation of "Features" as something very straightforward, but I can't seem to get through the process.

It looks like I have a string length issue. Where do I set the max length of a column input? (System >> Info).

Any tips? Any tutorials or videos that you recommend?

Comment: Also - I can't seem to figure out how to ensure that the new "Feature" shows up in the "Features" UI. I just read [this article](https://glamanate.com/blog/using-features-override-manage-changes-distribution), where it shows the new Override in the "Features" UI, but I don't see similar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Great news! Kind of.

After looking at the database more (using the [Database Admin module](https://www.drupal.org/project/dba)), I found that the "info" column is a BLOB. A BLOB has a max char length of 65,000.

Given the number of changes I made to the default settings, my Feature Override complete set of Feature Overrides well exceeded the 65,000 characters allotted. I opted to split the Feature Overrides into individual packets, grouped by type (variable / facetapi / user). This appears to have done the job. Fairly straightforward after better understanding the db setup and limitations there.

In terms of avoiding extensive overrides, I suspect that I created this snag by starting out with the demo store implemented in Commerce Kickstart. That option seemed like a good plan for me at the time because it provided some basic features already setup. I adapted those for what I need, but it may not be a particularly good foundation from which to grow the site. Any feedback there?